# Query not showing any results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a list of records from MySQL database using PHP, but for some reason I can’t get the desired result. Instead of a full list my select box are small an empty — they contain no options. Where’s the error in my code?

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'toor', 'monster');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL' .   mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
    function query() {

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM corporations");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' .$row['name']. '</option>';
        }
    }
?>

<select name='dropdown'>
    <?php query() ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What is it doing?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: Nothing show up. The option boxes are tiny and empty.

Comment: "Tiny and empty option boxes" isn't the same thing as "nothing".  Be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable scope. You're defining the connection string outside of the `query` function and so you cannot use it inside the function with out first passing in to the function in some way.

This should work:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'toor', 'monster');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL' . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

function query($con)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM corporations");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}

query($con);
```

Comment: Man, Such a simple fix yet I would have never got it. Many thanks to you bro.

Comment: Last question for you, When I submit this form. What will this query be in post?

Comment: I will accept it within 15 min, It makes me wait until then

Comment: Sure no worries! When you submit the form the `$_POST['dropdown']` variable will contain what ever option the user selected from the dropdown - is that what you mean?